# Can't install better-sqlite on ubuntu as root

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, npm, better-sqlite3

I want to install better-SQLite on my ubuntu server but I get the notification that I do not have enough permission to install it in that folder, how can I fix this?

(See photo for exact error)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fPA0.png

Comment: Check your folder permissions.

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+file+permissions

Comment: I think you are on the wrong site as StackOverflow is for questions around coding , but perhaps 'sudo' will help

Comment: and what file/folder do I need to give perms?